# Angular2 Frontend & .NET Core Backend Authentication / Account system

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core, account

I'm starting a little project and got stuck on the first part, the account management.

As the title states, I'm using Angular2 as frontend, connected to a .NET Core WEB API & Backend, which is connected to a MySQL DB trough Entity Framework.

Now I would like to know what the best account management / authentication system is for this stack?

I've read some things about JWT access tokens but couldn't find any full solution of running it on a stack like this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look to this blog http://andrewlock.net/.
This guy explain some way to explore about the authentification and authorization.

Otherwise, have a glance to IdentityServer v4 official documentation's. There are some clear example to implement your own SSO.
Also, check this blog https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4 .

I currently use these sources to build a SPA project with ASP.NET Core.

Enjoy and be patient :)